# IndexOutOfBoundsException while loop executes-Java

Tags: java

```
package com.cp.javapractice;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cp {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = null;
    str = new String();
    System.out.println("Enter the string which you want to remove the     duplicates");
    str = s.nextLine();
    String arr[] = str.split(" ");
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        al.add(arr[k]);
    }
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {

                if (arr[i].equalsIgnoreCase(arr[j])) {
                    al.remove(j);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(al);
        } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

I am going to replace the repeating words in particular given string from the user.  So, I split the given string with space using split method and put in array as well as in arraylist.

After Iterate through array and checked the condition it is equal then I removed that in ArrayList. But While removing it shows Index out of bound Exception.

This code is working for small array size but shows exception while giving large number of array size.
I am having problem while I am giving the string with array size of 13 words.

Here is my full code.

Comment: This is a great time to learn how to use a debugger!

Comment: You have omitted the critical information: The exception stack trace (complete) and an indication of which statement in your code throws the exception.  Please [edit] your question to include the missing information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IndexOutOfBoundsException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269153/indexoutofboundsexception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {

    for (int j = i + 1; j < al.size(); j++) {

        if (al.get(i).equals(al.get(j)) { 
            al.remove(j);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you remove that toLowerCase Conversion code? @VojtechRuzicka

Comment: Sorry, my bad, it was unitentional, just wanted to correct indentation.

Comment: I checked my edit and it only affects indents actually.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is because you are using `arr.length` instead of `al.size()`. For every removal, the size of the arraylist `al` decreases. So, you have to consider using size of arraylist instead of size of the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) { // change arr.length to al.size()

            for (int j = i + 1; j < al.size(); j++) { // change arr.length to al.size()

                if (arr[i].equalsIgnoreCase(arr[j])) {
                    al.remove(j);

                }
            }
        }
```

I would recommend you to check out `HashSet` and `TreeSet` which reduces your effort of removing duplicates.

---

Implementing in `HashSet`:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;


public class Cp {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = null;
    str = new String();
    System.out.println("Enter the string which you want to remove the     duplicates");
    str = s.nextLine();
    String arr[] = str.split(" ");

    Set<String> ts = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arr)); // -> added only this line

        System.out.println(ts);

}
}
```

Comment: Yes! Sets will reduce your effort for handling duplicate values. Good Suggestion. @SkrewEverything

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is your 2nd loop. Is Starts at i+1. But i is from 0 to length -1. So the Last ein will be j=length-1+1 which is beyond Array length.

So Change the 1st for loop to:

```
for(int i=0;i < arr.length-2;i++)
```